# KendoNumericTextbox not updating when value set

Tags: kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

I am having trouble updating  kendoNumericTextBox when I update the val it will not show until I put my cursor into the textbox.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
 
 $('#txtCorpEl').kendoNumericTextBox({}).data("kendoNumericTextBox");
 
 $('#txtCorpEl').value(5);
 
 $('#txtCorpEl').focus();
 
 //var numerictextbox = $("#txtCorpEl").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
//numerictextbox.focus();
 
 });
 
 
 function onChange() {
    console.log("event: change");
};
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2011.3.1129/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2011.3.1129/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>        
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2011.3.1129/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
 <input id="txtCorpEl" />
```

Comment: Try using their value function instead of jquery val http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/numerictextbox/api

Comment: Great suggestion  but ... "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).value is not a function"

Comment: You need to use theirs on their element. One moment.

Comment: I have added an answer that is working for me. Note that I use the function against their object, not a jquery element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working fine when I test it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2011.3.1129/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2011.3.1129/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>        
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2011.3.1129/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <input id="txtCorpEl" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtCorpEl").kendoNumericTextBox();
     var numerictextbox = $("#txtCorpEl").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
 numerictextbox.value(5); 
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still relevant and useful.